# Where is the latex template for IEEE Journal of Translational Engineering in Health?

Tags: publications, paper-submission, ieee, online-resource, latex

I was trying to find the latex template for IEEE Journal of Translational Engineering in Health and Medicine, but I am only able to find the .`doc` template. Do we have any .`tex` template for this journal?

http://ieeeauthorcenter.ieee.org/create-your-ieee-article/use-authoring-tools-and-ieee-article-templates/ieee-article-templates/templates-for-ieee-journal-of-translational-engineering-in-health-and-medicine/

Usually there should be latex template as well.

Comment: There is an IEEE Transactions LaTeX template.

Answer (score 1):

It seems JTEHM does not provide any template for LaTeX documents. The standard IEEE template is available with `\usepackage{ieeetran}` but it does not seems to be coherent with the word document provided (e.g. abstract), so it might need adaptation.

Comment: Maybe papers on "translational engineering in health and medicine" do not have any equations in them, so the editors think LaTeX is not needed.

Answer (score 1):

You could play with `IEEEtran` to generate the similar looking document template. This is what I could get.

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\title{Here goes my JTEHM Title}
\author{Author1, Author2, Author3 \\ Institute1, Address1\\ Institute2, Address2}
\begin{document}
\twocolumn[
\begin{@twocolumnfalse}
\maketitle
\end{@twocolumnfalse}
\begin{abstract}
~{\lipsum[1-1]}
\index{keyword1, keyword2, keyword3}
\end{abstract}
\bigskip]
\section{Introduction}
\lipsum[1-7]
\section{Conclusion}
\lipsum[1-1]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Looks like tex SE. *Was the question more fit for tex SE and somewhat-less fit for academia SE?*

Comment: Thanks, very similar, but minor differences. For instance, the first letter is Capital.

Comment: @TinaJ won't it be taken care by editorial team after acceptance.

Answer (score 0):

I contacted their office and looks like they don't have latex template. But they provided me with IEEE JERM tex template which is almost identical.
[image]